# Can react simply change CSS style by selector that's defined elsewhere

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

To start, I am working with [react-swipe-to-delete-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipe-to-delete-component), but I feel that should make little difference in the question.

I am trying to change the `background-color` property of a "built out" element.  I have no control over the class name as the plugin uses it, and I cannot assign it (I think) a separate class name as it stands.  Is there a way to change the style of a element solely based on selector, like in vanilla JavaScript?

I have this element `<SwipeToDelete>`.  It builds out a div that I need to access by the selector:

```
<div class="swipe-to-delete">
    <div class="js-delete">
```

And thus I need to be able to access

```
.swipe-to-delete .js-delete
```

as a selector.

Is there a way like in JS IE `document.getElementsByClassName('.swipe-to-delete .js-delete')[0].style.background-color = "#FFF")`

I need to change the background color based on which function is called:

```
const [isRight, setRight] = useState(false);
const [isLeft, setLeft] = useState(false);


const onLeft = (...args) => {
    // Make Mask Red with Icon
    console.log('Set left to true');
    setLeft(true);
}
const onRight = (...args) => {
    // Make Mask Green with icon
    console.log('Set right to true');
    setRight(true);
}


<SwipeToDelete
  onLeft={onLeft}
  onRight={onRight}
  >
```

This works.. I just don't know how to incorporate this pseudo statement

```
isRight ? '.swipe-to-delete .js-delete'.backgroundColor="green" : ''
```

Since I can't access `<SwipeToDelete>`'s inner workings to set a class name somewhere, without modifying the node-module code.  I really am stuck here.

I just want to simply change the background color of `.swipe-to-delete .js-delete` depending on right or left function.  Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Can't you change the background color of the element you set as the child element of `SwipeToDelete`?

Comment: @tadej The child element is simply an a tag that sits on top .. If you view the example [HERE](https://gaer87.github.io/react-swipe-to-delete-component/example/) .. I am trying to change what is BEHIND the swipe.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to change that red color that is shown when the element is dragged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `classNameTag` prop you can use to define a className on the wrapper element for `<SwipeToDelete>` (the element with `className="swipe-to-delete"`).

Based on the swipe direction you set the `className` accordingly:

```js
<SwipeToDelete
  classNameTag={isRight ? "is-right" : isLeft ? "is-left" : ""}
  onLeft={onLeft}
  onRight={onRight}
>
```

And styling with CSS:

```css
.swipe-to-delete.is-right .js-delete {
  background-color: green;
}
.swipe-to-delete.is-left .js-delete {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is close!  but once it's set to right or left .. I needed to set the opposite state to false ..  Thank you!